# How to list MySql alongside of COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table as such:

```
Article_Name   Category_ID
-------------  -----------
Penguins            20
Penguins            20
Penguins            20
Lions               20
Tigers              20
Tigers              20
Tigers              20
Tigers              20
Electricity         21
Power Plants        21
Buddhism            22
```

I want to list the output with a count in another table.  I can get the count and I can list the rows but I can not combine the two.  I am looking to get the output as such:

```
Article_Name      Count
-------------  -----------
Penguins            3
Lions               1
Tigers              4
```

I am getting my COUNT as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(Article_Name) FROM Votes WHERE Category_ID = '20' GROUP BY Article_Name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($result === FALSE) {                                                                                         die(mysqli_error());                                                                                    }
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {echo "HTML goes here";};
```

But that literally only gets me the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause groups all records for each `Article_Name` and then `COUNT()` function in conjunction with `GROUP BY` counts the number of `Category_ID` for each `Article_Name`.

Try this query:-

```
"SELECT Article_Name,COUNT(*)  
FROM Votes        
WHERE Category_ID = '20' GROUP BY Article_Name";
```

**Output**:-

```
+--------------+----------+
| Article_Name | COUNT(*) |
+--------------+----------+
| Penguins     |        2 | 
| Lions        |        1 | 
| Tigers       |        2 | 
+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Excellent. I was just going to say that. I had forgot a comma between the expr and COUNT. That was killing me.

Answer (score 1):

you already group by Article_Name, you just have to select it along with the count is already there.

```
$query = "SELECT Article_Name,COUNT(Article_Name) FROM Votes WHERE Category_ID = '20' GROUP BY Article_Name";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.